# Overloading description in Swagger file (YAML)

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have an issue writing my swagger file. When I describe a parameter the description is overloaded by the description of the $ref of this same parameter (see the example bellow).

```
a-body:
    description: The body
    type: object
    properties:
      my_param:
        description: Full description 
        $ref: '#/definitions/reference'

definitions:
    reference:
        type: object
        required: [req]
        description: an http reference
        properties:
          req:
            type: string
```

The result: 
[the description is overloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79aSj.png)

Can somebody help me get through this please ?

Answer (score 1):

`$ref` overwrites all of its sibling properties - it's how `$ref` works. You can try to work around this using something like:

```yaml
my_param:
  description: Full description 
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/reference'
```

This will work in Swagger Editor and Swagger UI.

There's also a [feature request](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/556) in the OpenAPI Specification repository to provide a better way to combine `$ref` with other properties.

Comment: I'm using a buggy plugin on vs code so it's not working but I can't do otherwise ! Thanks for your help !