# How to declare a $ref property as readOnly in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I am trying to add a read-only field for 'House' in this example. The house is another model that I want to be read-only.

In this example, the array of Dogs can be set to `readOnly` without an error, but when I set the single definition of House to `readOnly` I get the following warning in the Swagger Editor:

> Sibling values are not allowed alongside $refs

I understand that this is because everything in the model is inherited here. So how do I define that the write API calls cannot define a 'House' in this endpoint whilst also allowing House to be created and updated in another API endpoints?

```yaml
Pets:
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
      example: AAAAE12-1123AEF-1122312123
      readOnly: true
    name:
      type: string
      example: My Default Name
    text:
      type: string
      example: My Default Text
  Dogs:
    type: array
    readOnly: true
    items:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Dog'    
  House:
    readOnly: true
    $ref: '#/definitions/House'
```

Comment: Related (almost a duplicate): [Overloading description in Swagger file (YAML)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47155842/113116)

Answer (score 56):

### OpenAPI 3.1

In OAS 3.1, schema definitions support sibling keywords alongside `$ref`:

```yaml
House:
  $ref: '#/components/schemas/House'
  readOnly: true
```

### OpenAPI 3.0 and 2.0

Sibling keywords alongside `$ref` are ignored. The workaround is to use `allOf` to combine a `$ref` with other attributes:

```yaml
  House:
    readOnly: true
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/House'
```

Comment: Using this approach does not work cause `readonly` property won't appear in the output.

Comment: @MajidAkbari it's a tooling issue then. Open an issue with that tool.

Comment: It works on Swagger UI, but when you try to generate Client SDK (i.e. Java) the output Class are not correctly generated on `openapi: 3.0.x`. 
Hope with Codegone on `openapi: 3.1.x`.

Comment: Do you have a link to the spec? It's easier to issue feture requests to the tools if we have a proper reference.

Comment: @MikaKarjunen: For OpenAPI 3.1, the relevant spec links are https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#schema-object and [JSON Schema 2020-12, section 8.2.3.1](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core#section-8.2.3.1) (_'other keywords can appear alongside of "$ref" in the same schema object'_). For OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.0, the relevant links are https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.0#schema-object and [JSON Schema Draft 5, section 7](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wright-json-schema-00#section-7) (_'All other properties in a "$ref" object MUST be ignored.'_)

Answer (score 2):

I just have found the result and want to share with you like below, you can use readyonly attribute to hide any field:

- Java code:

`@ApiModelProperty(example = "1", readOnly = true, value = "User status")`

`public String getUserStatus() { return userStatus; }`

- Swagger:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzOYg.png)

Comment: No where in the question do they ask about Java. This answer is not helpful.

Comment: @techvice true, but it helped me, as i need to declare this via annotations

Comment: In the newer version of Swagger, the annotation is changed to
@Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on [Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen)'s answer

## OpenAPI 3.0.x

The solution with readonly next to allOf referencing schema definitions is not working with libraries like oas3-chow-chow, not sure if it's working with othters. I was able to make it work though shifting the readonly definition into the allOf block like following:

```
  House:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/House'
      - readOnly: true
```